# Difficulty performing complex sorting when listing files in a directory with the ls command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sorting, ls

The behavior I'm seeking is a nested sort with the ls command where sorting by one method doesn't cancel out sorting by a second method. The exact desired behavior is essentially:

First sort with directories first, files second, plus some aesthetic and readablility options:

`ls --group-directories-first -pAN -I ".*"`

Then, without undoing this sort, apply a group by extension for all of the files listed below the directories:

`ls -X`

Then, **within each extension subgroup only** sort each file alphabetically with numbers being ordered as they would if you were counting
(eg. 0,001,01,1..9,10,11..99,100..,A01,Ab,a,ab):

`ls -v`

Unfortunately, `ls -Xv` doesn't apply one sort after the other, but instead causes the -v option to cancel out the -X option. An example of one sort not canceling out the other would be `ls --group-directories-first -v` where directories being listed first takes precedent, then sorted by version with the -v option without overriding the priority that directories will be ordered before files.

A specific illustration of the behavior I'm looking for is as follows in an example directory:

```
aDirectory/
a01Directory/
Bdirecory/
b/
0
01
1
9
0010
010
10
100
101
Afile
aFile
afilE
afile
B01
B01a
Ba01
Ba 01
BA 02
Ba02
Ba 02
1.jpg
9.jpg
010.jpg
10.jpg
A.jpg
a.jpg
a01.jpg
a01 today.jpg
B.jpg
b.jpg
AnotherFile.txt
another01File.txt
another 01 File.txt
another File.txt
another File01.txt
Z.txt
```

Which is the equivalent of this command if -X and -v didn't conflict with each other:

```
ls --color=auto --group-directories-first -pANXv -I ".*"
```

I've tried different combinations of options with ls, piping ls into the sort command with different options, and piping ls into egrep with regular expressions. I can program in C and bashscript, so tips on writing a script or program is a perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. First the simplified version (can be bad with whitespace in filenames and especially the abnormal case of whitespace in the file extension)

```
ls -p |
  awk -F. '{ if ($0 ~ /\/$/ ) { print "!",$0 } else if ( NF == 1 ) { print "!!",$0 } else { print $NF,$0 } }' |
  sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2V | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

and the advanced version which can handle whitespace and includes your extra ls options

```
ls --color=auto -pANXv -I ".*" |
  awk -F. 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} { if ($0 ~ /\/$/ ) { print "\001",$0 } else if ( NF == 1 ) { print "\001\001",$0 } else { print $NF,$0 } }' |
  sort -t/ -k 1,1 -k 2,2V |
  cut -d/ -f2-
```

### How it works

- The `ls` part should be clear. The `--group-directories-first` option is not needed here.
- The `awk` command splits the filename at `.` and does one of three things

  1. if line ends with a `/` it is recognized as directory (that's why the `-p` option to `ls` is crucial) and awk will print one '1'-byte, the `OFS` character (space in the first example that's why it prints a `!` before) and finally the full directory name
  2. if name has no `.`, i.e. no file extension, awk will print two '1'-bytes (or `!!` for the simple version), the `OFS` character and again the full file name
  3. if name has a `.` awk will print the file extension (everything after the last `.`), the `OFS` character and again the full file name (including the file extension but that doesn't matter)
- So after the `awk` an input like

  ```
  directory/
  plain
  test.txt
  archive.tar.gz
  ```

  will be transformed to (I use ␁ to visualize the '1'-byte)

  ```
  ␁/directory/
  ␁␁/plain
  txt/test.txt
  gz/archive.tar.gz
  ```
- The `sort` will sort separately the two field divided by ␟. First one normally, the second one with with version sort (the `V` in `-k 2,2V`).
- The `cut` simply removes the first field which was the sort helper to group by extension.

Note that I have not tested this further with the influence of (Unicode) sort locales. The '1'-byte is chosen because it should sort first in most cases and one of them should sort before two of them.

PS: I first tried to build you something with the stable feature of `sort` but first of all I could not guarantee if it is actually as stable as someone would expect here and it would not work with directories having a `.` or files having multiple `.`. And the required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222810/sorting-on-the-last-field-of-a-line got me to the current solution instead.

```
ls --group-directories-first -v | sort --stable --field-separator=. --key=2
```

PPS: the `-A` plus `-I ".*"` is a weird combination. Doesn't that cancel out each other?